# $D=\{(x,y)\mid x\ge y,\,y \ge -2,x+y \le 1\}$ calculate $\iint_D (2x-3y)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

Draw the domain $D=\{(x,y) \mid x\ge y,y \ge -2, x+y \le 1\}$ and calculate the integral $$\iint_D (2x-3y)\,dx\,dy.$$
I have this problem solved but I don't understand how to calculate the limits and why are the integrals split in the solution.
$$\iint_D(2x-3y) \, dx \, dy=\int_{-2}^{\frac 12} \left(\int_{-2}^x(2x-3y) \, dy \right) \, dx + \int_{\frac12}^3 \left( \int_{-2}^{1-x}(2x-3y) \, dy \right) \, dx = .....\frac{225}{8}$$

Can someone explain to me how are the limits calculated and why is the integral split? Thanks!
$$

Comment: You wrote one of the limits wrong. Upper limit of 6th integral in the first row must be $1-x$ and also upper limit for the integral in the third row.

Comment: Thanks! That's how it was in the book, no wonder it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With problems like this, it really helps to draw a picture.  As you can see you end up with a triangle.  Moving up along the y axis you should be able to see from the picture that you move from -2 to the line x and then along the x axis you move from -2 to the peak with is at 1/2.  Now you have to readjust your boundary.  Similarly you should see that as you move along the y you start from the line 1 - x back to -2 and along the x axis you move from the peak at 1/2 down to 3.

[image: Image of the domain described]

Comment: one more question. Shouldn't I be able to do it without spliting the integrals if I integrated dx first instead of dy?

Comment: Don't believe so, you'll run into the same problem.  You'll start from y to the peak and from peak to y-1.  Either way you'll need to correct for the change in boundary somehow.